# Lidar cluster and classifier not output as expectation

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After run lidar cluster and classifier module(Single lidar) of autoware.auto, I found that the object output is not my expectation.
I expect the lidar algo can output object only for interest ones: car/truck/bus/bicycle/person etc.
But in fact it will output all the cluster points, the points from kerb/bushes/wall will also generate some dummy object. Of course, these objects is not what I need.
So I want to know whether autoware algo can output only interest object, if it is, what shall I do?
Below is the gif for reference.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387086/lidar-cluster-and-classifier-not-output-as-expectation/) by [daniel.tian](https://answers.ros.org/users/85315/daniel.tian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @daniel.tian

You need to process the point cloud produced by the lidar with a separate algorithm, as per documentation VoxelNet and LMNet are compatible:

"lidar_detector reads point cloud data from 3D laser scanners, and provides LiDAR-based object detection capabilities. The basic performance comes from the Euclidean Clustering algorithm, which finds clusters of the LiDAR scan (point cloud) above the ground. To classify the clusters, DNN-based algorithms are also supported, such as VoxelNet and LMNet."
https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Overview

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daniel.tian](https://answers.ros.org/users/85315/daniel.tian/) on 2021-09-22**:
Thanks for your reply Omar.
My project is based on autoware.auto framework, and searched in my project, it seems that there is no VoxelNet and LMNet in official autoware.auto project. I guess it is located in autoware.ai. If so, after copy from autoware.ai, can I build it and launch in autoware.auto directly? I am new to autoware, and not know the work load.
Many thanks.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-23**:
You will have to process the point cloud on a separate node. Here is an example using ROS https://github.com/AbangLZU/VoxelNetRos

Glad it helped. Pls remember to vote and if you have more questions start a new one. Good luck